# How do I set environment variables during the "docker build" process?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, environment-variables, docker-build

I'm trying to set environment variables in docker container during the build but without success. Setting them when using run command works but I need to set them during the build.

##### Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ARG TEST_ENV=something
```

##### Command I'm using to build

```bash
docker build -t --build-arg TEST_ENV="test" myimage .
```

##### Running

```bash
docker run -dit myimage
```

##### I'm checking available environment variables by using

```bash
docker exec containerid printenv
```

##### And the result is

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=e49c1abfd58b
TERM=xterm
no_proxy=*.local, 169.254/16
HOME=/root
```

`TEST_ENV` is not present

Answer (score 274, accepted):

`ARG` is for setting environment variables which are used during the `docker build` process - they are not present in the final image, which is why you don't see them when you use `docker run`.

You use `ARG` for settings that are only relevant when the image is being built, and aren't needed by containers which you run from the image. You can use `ENV` for environment variables to use during the build and in containers.

With this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG BUILD_TIME=abc
ENV RUN_TIME=123
RUN touch /env.txt
RUN printenv > /env.txt
```

You can override the build arg as you have done with `docker build -t temp --build-arg BUILD_TIME=def .`. Then you get what you expect:

```
> docker run temp cat /env.txt                                                                                         
HOSTNAME=b18b9cafe0e0                                                                                                  
RUN_TIME=123                                                                                                           
HOME=/root                                                                                                             
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin                                                      
BUILD_TIME=def                                                                                                         
PWD=/
```

Comment: Using `ENV` added the environment variable but using `docker build -t temp --build-arg BUILD_TIME=def` prints "One or more build-args [BUILD_TIME] were not consumed, failing build.".

Adding separate `ARG BUILD_TIME_ARG=default` and `ENV BUILD_TIME=$BUILD_TIME_ARG` helped. Could you add it to your answer? 

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I just realised that you can make `ARG` with the same name as the `ENV`. `ARG BUILD_TIME=default` `ENV BUILD_TIME=$BUILD_TIME`

Comment: Ironically Elton's answer is not the correct one. Michael's last comment hit the nail on the head and shows how to actually set an environment variable via a build (at the time of this writing).

Comment: @KenJ Yes, but naming a runtime variable BUILD_TIME is somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 242):

I'll summarize highlights from [this](https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/) great article.

---

### ARG Vs ENV

***1 ) Short explanation:***

**ARG** is only available during the build of a Docker image (RUN etc), not after the image is created and containers are started from it (ENTRYPOINT, CMD).

**ENV** values are available to containers, but also RUN-style commands during the Docker build starting with the line where they are introduced.
If you set an environment variable in an intermediate container using bash (RUN export VARI=5 && …) it will not persist in the next command.

***2 ) Longer explanation:*** 

**ARG** are also known as build-time variables. They are only available from the moment they are ‘announced’ in the Dockerfile with an ARG instruction up to the moment when the image is built. Running containers can’t access values of ARG variables. This also applies to CMD and ENTRYPOINT instructions which just tell what the container should run by default. If you tell a Dockerfile to expect various ARG variables (without a default value) but none are provided when running the build command, there will be an error message.

However, ARG values can be easily inspected after an image is built, by viewing the docker history of an image. Thus they are a poor choice for sensitive data.

**ENV** variables are also available during the build, as soon as you introduce them with an ENV instruction. However, unlike ARG, they are also accessible by containers started from the final image. ENV values can be overridden when starting a container, more on that below.

***3 ) With diagrem:*** 

Here is a simplified overview of ARG and ENV availabilities around the process around building a Docker image from a Dockerfile, and running a container.

They overlap, but ARG is not usable from inside the containers.

[image]

### Setting ARG and ENV values

#### Setting ARG values

So, you have your `Dockerfile`, which defines `ARG` and `ENV` values. How to set them, and where? You can leave them blank in the `Dockerfile`, or set default values. If you don’t provide a value to expected ARG variables which don’t have a default, you’ll get an error message.

Here is a `Dockerfile` example, both for default values and without them:

```
ARG some_variable_name
# or with a hard-coded default:
#ARG some_variable_name=default_value

RUN echo "Oh dang look at that $some_variable_name"
# you could also use braces - ${some_variable_name}
```

When building a Docker image from the commandline, you can set `ARG` values using `–build-arg`:

```
$ docker build --build-arg some_variable_name=a_value
```

Running that command, with the above `Dockerfile`, will result in the following line being printed (among others): *Oh dang look at that a_value*

So, how does this translate to using `docker-compose.yml` files? 
When using docker-compose, you can specify values to pass on for `ARG`, in an args block:
(docker-compose.yml file)

```
version: '3'

services:
  somename:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        some_variable_name: a_value
```

When you try to set a variable which is not `ARG` mentioned in the `Dockerfile`, Docker will complain.

#### Setting ENV Values

So, how to set `ENV` values? You can do it when starting your containers (and we’ll look at this a bit below), but you can also provide default `ENV` values directly in your `Dockerfile` by hard-coding them. Also, you can set dynamic default values for environment variables!

When building an image, the only thing you can provide are `ARG` values, as described above. You can’t provide values for `ENV` variables directly. However, both `ARG` and `ENV` can work together. You can use ARG to set the default values of `ENV` vars. 
Here is a basic `Dockerfile`, using hard-coded default values:

```
# no default value
ENV hey
# a default value
ENV foo /bar
# or ENV foo=/bar

# ENV values can be used during the build
ADD . $foo
# or ADD . ${foo}
# translates to: ADD . /bar
```

And here is a snippet for a `Dockerfile`, using dynamic on-build env values:

```
# expect a build-time variable
ARG A_VARIABLE
# use the value to set the ENV var default
ENV an_env_var=$A_VARIABLE
# if not overridden, that value of an_env_var will be available to your containers!
```

Once the image is built, you can launch containers and provide values for `ENV` variables in three different ways, either from the command line or using a `docker-compose.yml` file. 
All of those will override any default `ENV` values in the `Dockerfile`. 
 Unlike `ARG`, you can pass all kinds of environment variables to the container. Even ones not explicitly defined in the `Dockerfile`. 
It depends on your application whether that’ll do anything however.

**Option 1: Provide values one by one**
From the commandline, use the -e flag:

```
$ docker run -e "env_var_name=another_value" alpine env
```

From a `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  plex:
    image: linuxserver/plex
      environment:
        - env_var_name=another_value
```

**Option 2: Pass environment variable values from your host**
It’s the same as the above method. 
The only difference is, you don’t provide a value, but just name the variable. This will make Docker access the current value in the host environment and pass it on to the container.

```
$ docker run -e env_var_name alpine env
```

For the `docker-compose.yml` file, leave out the equation sign and everything after it for the same effect.

```
version: '3'

services:
  plex:
    image: linuxserver/plex
      environment:
        - env_var_name
```

**Option 3: Take values from a file (env_file)** 
Instead of writing the variables out or hard-coding them (not in good taste according to the 12-factor folks), we can specify a file to read values from. The contents of such a file look something like this:

```
env_var_name=another_value
```

The file above is called env_file_name (name arbitrary) and it’s located in the current directory. 
You can reference the filename, which is parsed to extract the environment variables to set:

```
$ docker run --env-file=env_file_name alpine env
```

With `docker-compose.yml` files, we just reference a env_file, and Docker parses it for the variables to set.

```
version: '3'

services:
  plex:
    image: linuxserver/plex
    env_file: env_file_name
```

### Common ways to set ARG and ENV from the command line

Here is a small cheat sheet, combining an overview of `ARG` and `ENV` availability with common ways to set them from the command line.

[image]

Comment: if I don't set the environment variable, what is the default environment variable in the container? Will it follow the host environment?

Comment: If you haven't configured any env vars in the Dockerfile it will contain just the default vars (probably more system level) that comes with the base images. Not the host's.

Comment: this answer is worth it for the cheat sheet alone. thanks :)

Comment: Is is better to put a .env file inside the container or load the ENV values into the environment of the container?

Comment: @Zaffer, both choices are valid, it really depends on the case or how it is easier to consume it in code (read env vars or from file which might be slower).

Comment: as you say, since args can be inspected after the fact, they are not a good choice for secrets.  what _would_ be a good choice for secrets?  Is there a different way?  If not, is there a way to scrub build args out of the final image?