# docker build with --build-arg with multiple arguments

Tags: docker, build, arguments

According to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg), it's possible to define multiple args for the flag `--build-arg`, but I can't find out how. I tried the following:

```
docker build -t essearch/ess-elasticsearch:1.7.6 --build-arg number_of_shards=5 number_of_replicas=2 --no-cache .
```

=> This returns an error.

I also tried:

```
docker build -t essearch/ess-elasticsearch:1.7.6 --build-arg number_of_shards=5,number_of_replicas=2 --no-cache .
```

=> This sets one variable, `number_of_shards`, to the value "5,number_of_replicas=2"

Any idea how I can define multiple arguments?

Answer (score 862, accepted):

Use `--build-arg` with each argument.

If you are passing two argument then add `--build-arg` with each argument like:

```
docker build \
-t essearch/ess-elasticsearch:1.7.6 \
--build-arg number_of_shards=5 \
--build-arg number_of_replicas=2 \
--no-cache .
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up.  The `--help` on this is especially misleading: `--build-arg list`.   It's not a list!

Comment: Maybe it's deprecated... I keep receiving `"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.`

Comment: The `exactly 1 argument` that's required is the directory (the `.` at the end of this example).

Comment: For multiline `--build-arg`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50299998/432903

Comment: If that is the case then the documentation seems wrong.  According to "docker build --help" the --build_arg is described as a list.  it isn't really specifying a list if I have to repeat the entire argument over and over with a single value each time.

Comment: the `"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.` error message is misleading! make sure the argument you're passing is not empty! (e.g. if you are injecting a variable into your docker build command). And as mentioned, you need a separate build-arg flag for each arg you want to pass.

Answer (score 193):

The above answer by pl_rock is correct, the only thing I would add is to expect the ARG inside the Dockerfile if not you won't have access to it. So if you are doing

```
docker build -t essearch/ess-elasticsearch:1.7.6 --build-arg number_of_shards=5 --build-arg number_of_replicas=2 --no-cache .
```

Then inside the Dockerfile you should add

```
ARG number_of_replicas
ARG number_of_shards
```

I was running into this problem, so I hope I help someone (myself) in the future.

Comment: you helped me also, so thanks. Let me add only that `ARGS` must be declared after `FROM`

Comment: Wow thanks! Using `ARG` is not even mentioned in https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg and `--build-arg` was useless for me without `ARG`

Comment: Also useless for me before FROM... :-/

Comment: Note, if you plan to utilize the env variables once your container has started you use the same patters except your docker file will use ENV instead of ARG https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597925/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-during-the-build-in-docker

Comment: Lost way to many time with this. FYI, here is the documentation which states that ARG must be used after FROM (well it can for all step before FROM if I read correctly)

Answer (score 72):

If you want to use environment variable during build. Lets say setting username and password.

```
username= Ubuntu
password= swed24sw
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ARG SMB_PASS
ARG SMB_USER
# Creates a new User
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash $SMB_USER
# Enters the password twice.
RUN echo "$SMB_PASS\n$SMB_PASS" | smbpasswd -a $SMB_USER
```

**Terminal Command**

`docker build --build-arg SMB_PASS=swed24sw --build-arg SMB_USER=Ubuntu . -t IMAGE_TAG`

Comment: Beware that this leaves the secret values visible in the docker image using the `docker history` command.

Answer (score 19):

It's a shame that we need multiple ARG too, it results in multiple layers and slows down the build because of that, and for anyone also wondering that, currently [there is no way](https://forums.docker.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-specify-multiple-arg-in-one-line/27384) to set multiple ARGs per one line.

Comment: this can be combined with [multi stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) to reduce layers on the final built image

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to set multiple build args. With buildkit you won't see separate steps being performed, and with the classic build, those additional steps are not filesystem layers.

Comment: This answer can be misleading.  What is true is that there is no way to set multiple arguments in one line.  But, multiple args are definitely supported.

Comment: Clarified the statement

Comment: ARG instruction does not create a new layer in modern Docker.
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers

Answer (score 15):

In case you want to pass automatically build arguments from a specific file, you can do it this way :

```
docker build  $(cat .my-env-file-name | while read line; do out+="--build-arg $line"; done; echo $out; out="") .
```

Comment: i cant figure out why but if you put quotes around the command substitution $() causes docker build to break. it loses the '=value' part. this was driving me nuts for a while here! any idea why?

Comment: get_build_args() {
  for build_arg in "${BUILD_ARGS[@]}"; do
    out+="--build-arg $build_arg "
  done

  echo -n "$out"
}

i wrote this assuming BUILD_ARGS is an array with elements ARG_NAME=VALUE. it works well and when i echo the output its all there. however when substituted in to docker build if i put quotes around it then it breaks. really confused

Comment: example:

  build_args=\`get_build_args\`
  echo $build_args
  echo "$build_args"
  docker build $build_args .
  docker build "$build_args" .

Answer (score 8):

A way to pass in build arguments from a file using `xargs` is as follows:

```
cat .MY_ENV_FILE | xargs printf -- '--build-arg %s\n' | xargs docker build -t MY_TAG .
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31050917)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to pl_rock. This syntax worked for me in my gitlab pipeline (running alpine linux):

```
  script:
    - echo "attempting a multi-line build"
    - |
      docker build \
      --build-arg USER=${USER} \
      --build-arg PASSWORD=${PASSWORD} \
      -t ${IMAGE} \
      -f Dockerfile .
    - echo "Great Success"
```