# Set Multiline Environment Variable with Dockerfile

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I want to set a multiline environment variable in my Dockerfile.

### Works through command line

If I pass in the environment variable through `docker run` everything works.

```
CONFIG="port: 4466
databases:
  prod:
    connector: mysql
    active: true
    host: 33.333.333.333
    port: 3306
    user: root
    password: pass"
docker run --env CONFIG="$CONFIG" ubuntu:latest env | grep 'CONFIG'
```

Output (its only a single line because its interpreted as multiline variable)

```
CONFIG=port: 4466
```

### Doesnt Work through dockerfile

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV CONFIG 'port: 4466\ndatabases:\n  prod:\n    connector: mysql\n    active: true\n    host: host\n    port: 3306\n    user: root\n    password: pass'
```

Build and run the docker image

```
docker build -t multilinetest .
docker run multilinetest env | grep 'CONFIG'
```

Output

```
CONFIG=port: 4466\ndatabases:\n  prod:\n    connector: mysql\n    active: true\n    host: host\n    port: 3306\n    user: root\n    password: pass
```

### Expected

Both scenarios should store the same environment variable (I'm passing this environment variable into a 3rd party image that requires a multiline string)

Answer (score 24):

I was able to get this working by passing the multiline environment variable as a build arg to docker build.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ARG CONFIG
ENV CONFIG $CONFIG
```

**Build Command**

```
CONFIG="port: 4466
databases:
  prod:
    connector: mysql
    active: true
    host: 33.333.333.333
    port: 3306
    user: root
    password: pass"
docker build --build-arg CONFIG="$CONFIG" ubuntu:latest env | grep 'CONFIG'
```

Answer (score 10):

Escaping newline characters work fine.

#### Dockerfile

```
ENV BUILD_DEPENDENCIES apt-utils \
  curl \
  libc-dev \
  gcc \
  gnupg2
```

#### Output

```
Step 8/48 : ENV BUILD_DEPENDENCIES apt-utils   curl   libc-dev   gcc   gnupg2
 ---> Running in 65b0ad105af4
```

Comment: This is not actually the solution because this turns newlines into nothing,