# How to authenticate Docker container with Google Service

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

The Docker container runs a Python server and publishes messages to `Google Pubsub` message service.

In order for this container to be able to use `Google Pubsub` service I set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable pointing it to `service_key.json` file that I downloaded after creating a `Service Account Key` by opening `Google Cloud Console` and then navigation to:

`API's & Services` > `Credentials` > `Create Credentials` > `Service Account Key`.

[image]

[image]

The `service_key.json` file needs to be copied to a container's local disk otherwise it won't be able to read it.

While this approach works and the Docker container is now authorized to use Google Pubsub service with the `service_key.json` file credentials I believe it is not a very secure solution since the `service_key.json` file is now hosted on a cloud with the container itself.

Is there a way to authorize the Docker container with the Google Service credentials without copying `service_key.json` file to its local disk?

Comment: Where are you deploying this Docker container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you doing something like this?

```
docker run ...
--volume=${LOCAL_PATH}/secrets/service_key.json:/secrets/key.json \
--env=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/service/key.json \
mycontainerimage
```

**NB** Remapping `service_key.json` --> `key.json` for clarity of intent

This doesn't address the need to mount the key on the host running the container but it does address the need to put the key *in* the container.

As long as you can secure the host (!), the key will be reasonably secure. You should include a process whereby you rotate keys frequently too. This requires more work in (re)distributing keys but it reduces the risk of lost keys.

Using keys, you're always going to have to protect the key while exposing it at potentially insecure locations.

If your containers are running on a Google Cloud Platform compute service (App Engine, Compute, Kubernetes, Run), Application Default Credentials can use the resource's service account (no key).

For other types of credentials (to my knowledge not Google Service Accounts), you may also consider key management services including Cloud KMS, HashiCorp Vault.

Answer (score 0):

Based on there documentation

https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-pubsub/latest/file.AUTHENTICATION.html

set the contents of the json file to this variable

> PUBSUB_CREDENTIALS - Path to JSON file, or JSON contents

This other [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299617/set-multiline-environment-variable-with-dockerfile) may help you address multi-line issues when tring to set this with docker run (this post references "docker build", but same idea)