# How to save IP to the environment Variable in docker file?

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile, ip

I have an usecase to get the host IP inside Dockerfile and save it to ENV value, but I am not able to successfully achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Below is my Sample Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-11
ENV IP=${"`ip -4 route show default | cut -d\" \" -f3`"}
RUN echo $IP
```

Comment: You mean IP of a hosting machine?

Comment: @alexey R. Yes.. the above command gives host ip..I understood in Linux,it is always 172.17.0.1.. but I don't want to hard code it..

Comment: No, that is not always what you think. Host might (and usually do) have several IPs. 127.x.x.x is a loopback IP range, but there are also IPs assigned to network interfaces such as WiFi and ethernet adapters.

Comment: Ok, agree, so that's also the reason not to hard code it, since as you said it may change. I want to set IP to ENV of Dockerfile.

Comment: Can you add more details on what is the result of your trial? Do you have image built like you are showing and you cannot see that set env when you're inside a container?

Comment: `failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to process "${\"`ip -4 route show default | cut -d\\\" \\\" -f3`\"}": missing ':' in su
bstitution`

I am getting above error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236820/discussion-between-sen-and-alexey-r).

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating ENV value on build stage is not supported. See the thread here https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29110

Since your app needs this value on execution phase you can build your image just from

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-11
```

and then build it like this

```
docker build -t maven .
```

and then execute like this:

```
docker run -ti -e IP=$(ip -4 route show default | cut -d" " -f3) maven /bin/bash
```

Here is the result visible in container:

```
root@6856d118d02b:/# echo $IP
192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Sorry, I think some quotes are missing.. I am getting below error 

`failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: Syntax error - can't find = in "-4". Must be of the form: name=value`

Comment: I will check, but I am having some operations with IP inside Dockerfile. So not sure, if this solution suits my need..

Comment: In this case you can use ARG/--build-arg combination like it is shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54887094/8343843

Answer (score 0):

I think Dockerfile just be used to build image，at that time the container IP isn't confirmed。

You can set it  in  your start.sh or use `docker run -e`