# How to set environment variable when creating a Docker image

Tags: dockerfile, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm pretty new to Docker and I have the following requirement:

I need to create a new Docker image (via Dockerfile) that used as `FROM` in a Bitbucket Pipelines
and this image sets an environment variable that captures current Git feature-branch name.

Here is my attempt:

```
FROM maven:3.8.1-openjdk-8-slim

..
..

ENV GIT_FEATURE_BRANCH_NAME RUN (git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
..
```

Will this work? I would like it to be accessed from bitbucket_pipelines.yml file by doing `$GIT_FEATURE_BRANCH_NAME`

Any thoughts on that?
Thanks!

Comment: Ideally you don't want to hardcode the env vars directly into the images and instead you want to pass them when you run them

Comment: Otherwise look into ARG https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597925/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-during-the-build-in-docker

Comment: I see what you mean, but the idea is to put a variable/function in the docker image that would be evaluated only when running in Bitbucket pipelines. so I don't need to pass any arguments to the image, I just would like to have like a macro/variable/placeholder whatever so I can call it at runtime. makes sense?