# How to pass environment variables to FROM statement in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm starting to use Docker and I'm creating a Dockerfile.
The image I use for the FROM statement has environment variables to configure it, but I don't know how to pass the variables to this image. To do this I just need to set the ENV in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set environment variables during the build in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39597925/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-during-the-build-in-docker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes set the env variable using `ARG NAME_OF_ENV_VARIABLE` in dockerfile

and while building the docker image use `--build-arg` Flag.

example:

`docker build -t nameOfImage --build-arg NAME_OF_ENV_VARIABLE=ADD_YOUR_VALUE_TO_PASS .`